# Subversion with MacVim configured as the editor

Tags: svn, macvim

I'm using Subversion to checkin a file on OSX. I have my `EDITOR` variable configured to MacVim

My `.profile` includes:

```
export EDITOR=/Applications/MacVim/mvim
```

When I checkin with the `-m` option (`svn ci somefile`), MacVim gets launched but then Subversion immediately displays:

```
Log message unchanged or not specified
(a)bort, (c)ontinue, (e)dit:
```

It displays this before I get a chance to save my log message in MacVim.

Is there a way to get SVN to use MacVim as the log message editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to run mvim with the `-f` flag so that it stays in the foreground.  By default, it forks and returns control to the terminal which makes subversion think it is done.

Answer (score 4):

Apple Terminal:

```
export EDITOR='mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"'
```

or for iTerm or iTerm2:

```
export EDITOR='mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a iTerm"'
```

From "[Faq - macvim - GitHub](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/FAQ): How can I use MacVim to edit Git commit messages?".  I've confirmed that it works with Subversion, as well.

Answer (score 0):

See `open --help`:

> -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).

```
export EDITOR="open --wait -a /Applications/MacVim/mvim"
```

If the above doesn't work, you may need to put it into shell script and make $EDITOR to point that script. [EDIT: doesn't work, see the comment below.]

Comment: open would work for the `MacVim.app` application bundle. `mvim` is the command line tool, which would require the `-f` flag described above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using textmate as my svn editor and I had the same problem you had. But my solution is to set textmate to wait until the file is closed.

I added this in my .bash_profile

```
export SVN_EDITOR="mate -w"
```

-w is for wait